# Vispy Display on Second Screen

Tags: python, opengl, vispy

I am using Vispy to display some real-time signals, based on the example on the webpage.  In particular I'm using app.Canvas to create and update the display.

Is there a way to specify geometry information when then canvas is created?  Ideally I'd like to specify the size, coordinates and monitor for the new window.  But specifying the monitor is the most important part.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify canvas size and position by doing :

```
from vispy import app
pos_x, pos_y, width, height = 200, 200, 200, 200 #example
canvas = app.Canvas(size=(width, height), position=(pos_x, pos_y))
canvas.show()
app.run()
```

Have you tried to specify the monitor by adjusting the position ?